# Associative array returns undefined index even though index is clearly defined

Tags: php, associative-array

I have the following (stripped down) code:

```
$question = fetch_question($conn, $current_question);
var_dump($question);
echo $question["_id"];
```

`fetch_question()` uses `$conn` database connection to retrieve an array on `$current_question`.

This gives me the following output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["question"]=>
    string(10) "What's 2+2"
    ["answer1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["answer2"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["answer3"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["answer4"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["is_right"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: _id in <b>D:\Websites\htdocs\tests\general.php</b> on line <b>76</b><br />
```

Now I find this very peculiar, `_id` is clearly defined I have no idea what makes PHP behave like this!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only after seeing the output here on StackOverflow have I realized that I actually needed `$question[0]["_id"]`.

Well, we all know these little pest peeves.